# how to transfer a python object between two requests?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i want to process a python dict object in batches between two requests. i was wondering what's the best way to do it.

i want to do that because my dict is big and i couldn't do the whole processing in 30s.

thanks

Comment: What sort of processing? Why is it so big? Are you saving too much useless data?

Comment: thanks for your reply Hamish. i effectively haven't tested. but my requests have been killed in the past so these are mere speculations :) let me test and see then.

Comment: Ok ... you've got to tell us what you are doing - it would help.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize your object (perhaps with [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle), though there may be more efficient and specific ways if your object's nature is well-constrained) and save the serialized byte string to the datastore and to [memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html) (I **don't** recommend using *just* memcache, because it just might occasionally happen that the cache is "flushed" between the two requests -- in that case, you definitely want to be able to fetch your serialized byte string from the datastore!).

`memcache` will to the pickling for you, if you pass the original object -- but, since you need the serialized string anyway to put it in the datastore, I think it's better to do your own explicit serialization.  Once you `memcache.add` a string, the fact that the latter gets pickled (and later unpickled on retrieval) is not a big deal -- the overhead of time and space is really quite modest.

There are limits to this approach -- you can't memcache more than 1MB per key, for example, so if your object's truly huge you need to split up the serialized bytestring onto multiple keys (and for more than a few such megabyte-slices, things get very unwieldy).

Also, of course, the first and the second request must "agree" on a key to use for the serialized data's storage and retrieval -- i.e. there must be a simple way to get that key without confusion (for example, it might be based on the name of the current user).